# ffmpeg / avconv error while using a discord bot slash cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js, google-text-to-speech

## Code

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    PermissionFlagsBits,
    PermissionsBitField,
    EmbedBuilder,
  } = require("discord.js");

    const { generateDependencyReport, AudioPlayerStatus, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource  } = require('@discordjs/voice'); 
  const googleTTS = require("google-tts-api");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName(`tts`)
    .setDescription(`Fai ripetere al bot un messaggio in un canale vocale`)
    .addStringOption((option) =>
        option
          .setName("messaggio")
          .setDescription("Scrivi il messaggio da far ripetere dal bot in vocale")
          .setRequired(true)
      )
    .addBooleanOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName("rallentatore")
      .setDescription("Vuoi che il messaggio sia mandato a rallentatore?")
      .setRequired(true)
  ),  
  async execute(interaction, client) {

    const testo = interaction.options.getString("messaggio");
    const slow = interaction.options.getBoolean("rallentatore");



     const url = googleTTS.getAudioUrl(testo, {
        lang: "it",
        slow: slow,
        host: 'https://translate.google.com',
      });

      


      const { generateDependencyReport, AudioPlayerStatus, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource  } = require('@discordjs/voice');



      const voiceChannelId = interaction.member.voice.channel.id
        const voiceChannel = interaction.member.voice.channel
        const guildId = interaction.guild.id

        
        const player = createAudioPlayer();

    

        const resource = createAudioResource(url);
        player.play(resource);

        
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: voiceChannelId,
            guildId: guildId,
            adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });    



        const subscription = connection.subscribe(player);


        if (subscription) {
            setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 30_000);
        }

 
    
  },
};
```

## Error

```js
Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!
    at Function.getInfo (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:143:11)
    at Function.create (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:156:38)
    at new FFmpeg (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:45:27)
    at Object.transformer (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:1699:27)
    at C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:1855:58
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createAudioResource (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\node_modules\@discordjs\voice\dist\index.js:1855:39)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\src\commands\tools\tts.js:56:26)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\src\events\client\interactionCreate.js:13:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Casa\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord\eKicks\eKicks Bot v14\src\functions\handlers\handleEvents.js:20:23)
```

*i am making a command to play a message in a voice channel. Once this error was returned from the terminal I installed ffmpeg by creating an environment variable and installed python. I don't understand why it keeps giving this error. below I am attaching a picture of the npm list*

[image: npm list]

*maybe I also have to install avconv but I don't know how to do it, could you please attach the link? do i need to add avconv to the environment variables as well?*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

because installing it from npm did not work and I have no idea why.

Comment: you mean npm install ffmpeg0 ?